# Salesforce Email Blast

Tags: email

I am trying to send an email blast through Salesforce, and I am running into a few problems.

1)  How do I send an email blast when there are more than 250 contacts on an account?
2)  When I tried creating a new template, after clicking make available for use, it is not showing anything.
3)  After my email template does show in Salesforce,  will I able to have a greeting line?

We are using unlimited version.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are planning to use workflow email alert for email communication.

1. You can send to more than 250 contacts. But to trigger, you might
   have to update all contacts. Or you can go for apex batch class
   also.
2. If you make template available, it should be available in
   email alert to select. If it is not coming, you should raise ticket
   with salesforce.
3. Surely you can add greeting line. You can use merge fields for it.

Comment: Hi Victor, I am new to this so dont mind if i reply irrelevantly. I am an admin and I was assigned with this task. So is there any other way to send an email blast. or writing a workflow is the only option.?

Comment: If you write workflow also, you need to trigger it someway(update through dataloader or something). Other way would be to write a batch class to send email. This then you can schedule whenever you like.

Comment: Hi vctor can u brief me about how to add the greeting.?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the contacts tab, and on the main screen you will see an option to 'Mass Email Contacts'

[image: Shows Mass Email Contacts]

Select that option and then review the help or video demo of how to use the tool. I think this is what you are looking for.

Marc